# Is it possible to define such malloc and free that their data will be managed by GHC runtime?

Tags: haskell, memory-management, ghc

I have a source-distributed third-party library written in C, and I want to integrate it into a haskell project. This library is a minefield of contrived memory management (some functions take ownership of pointers, some don't), so I would like to not do it myself.

This library provides an option of defining custom `malloc` and `free` functions. I was wondering if I could have something similar to Boehm GC, but for GHC runtime. Does something like that exist? Is it even possible to implement since GHC gc relies on immutability?

Comment: [ForeignPtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html)?

Comment: @DanielWagner I believe ForeignPtr assumes haskell takes ownership of the object, but in my case the library can sometimes (at an unpredictable point in time) take the ownership back and free the object. Am I correct that ForeignPtr won't work in this case?

Comment: You can have your `free` implementation call `finalizeForeignPtr`.